# Index was outside the bounds of array when using List<Func<T,object>>

Tags: c#, func

I have a class like this:

```
class MyClass { public object[] Values; }
```

Somewhere else I'm using it:

```
MyClass myInstance = new MyClass() {Values = new object[]{"S", 5, true}};

List<Func<MyClass, object>> maps = new List<Func<MyClass, object>>();

for (int i = 0; i < myInstance.Values.Length ; i++)
{
    maps.Add(obj => obj.Values[i]);
}

var result = maps[0](myInstance); //Exception: Index outside the bounds of the array
```

I thought it will returns `S`, but it throw exception. Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To see what's going on, change your lambda to `maps.Add(obj => i);`.

With that change `result` will be `3`, and that's why you're getting `IndexOutOfBoundException` exception: you're trying to get `myInstance[3]` which does not exist.

To make it work, add local `int` variable within your loop and use that one as index instead of loop counter `i`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myInstance.Values.Length; i++)
{
    int j = i;
    maps.Add(obj => obj.Values[j]);
}
```

Comment: Yes, it solved the problem. but can you explain why the `i` value is acting like reference values?

Comment: @BolucPapuccuoglu +1 yes that's right. I didn't know its name.